# Entity Framework Core only saving one (the last) of a list of sub children

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

OK this is a free system for a homeless charity so extra brownie points for anyone who can help!

I've watched an entire course of Julie Lermans E.F Core to try to find the problem with this, it has completely blown my mind so am hoping someone can spot something!!

I have a one to many relationship by where I have a NightshelterRegister and that register will have many NightshelterRegisterAttendances. My 2 classes are below and as you can see have navigation properties each side.

[image]

My repo function to save is fairly simple:
[image]

As you can see at the point of hitting SaveChanges() the child list has 3 objects in it:
[image]

However only 1 of the 3 child records (the last in the list) is being saved to the database along with the parent record:
[image]

I'm at a complete loss with this. The database has correctly got the fk from the attendance table to the parent table:
[image]

It's a bit rough but you get the idea for the mapper function:
[image]

And finally my context:
[image]

I've wasted 3 days on this now and it's seriously holding up the charity getting their new system so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Simon, can you see the state of those entities? You have to do it through context state manager e.g. context.changetracker.entries. In there you can see the entities grouped by their state

Comment: The problem is apparently in your mapping function. Could you post it as code rather than as picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you step through `MapNightshelterRegisterAttendance` and see if it is adding 3 **new** records or adding the same record 3 times.

If the latter then I think that the same record id will be used for the three "saves" so it will look like only the last record is saved... (?)

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that's the issue. Just wanted to get op code to show him the mistake. +1 though for spotting it.

Comment: Oh nooooo..... I can see where you guys are going. The id in var existingAttendance = register.NightshelterRegisterAttendances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == nightshelterRegisterAttendance.Id)  for new records is always going to be 0, so it is adding the same record. I could cry (in pain and joy!). I will just double check this and let you know once confirmed. Thanks so much for this!

Comment: but if it's just the mapper, then that should be an easy tweak to your code.

Comment: I can confirm this is now working. I was being blinded by the fact I had 3 records waiting to be saved. Thank you all for your help!!